# Are there functions such that $f^{(k)}(x) > f^{(k-1)}(x)$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: functions, derivatives

Is it possible to have a function $f(x)$ which is infinitely differentiable and whose derivatives are all continuous such that $^\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $f^{(k)}(x) > f^{(k-1)}(x)$? If so, are there an interesting and unintuitive properties of such functions?

Comment: How about $f(x) = e^{2x}$?

Comment: ... I feel silly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=e^{4x}$$ where  $x \in \mathbb {R}$ will meet your condition.